# Can typescript validate string with a specific suffix?

Tags: typescript

I wonder if there is something like this in ts:

```js
type AudioFilename = "*.mp3"

const file1: AudioFilename = "textfile.txt" // Error
const file2: AudioFilename = "audiofile.mp3"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [Template Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html).

```
type AudioFilename = `${string}.mp3`
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAggVwCYEsD2AxFAbKA7AQwFtYBeGAAwBIBvAZxACcU8BzAXwDoiIBmC4MADGaPAxgAzHFACMALnjJ0WXIRIxyAIhBQAHiCm5OIfZpgB6czACijRmkbDR4w1ABMCxKkzS1ZGJoESmiu3HyaQA)